# ¿COMO CREAR TIPOS SESIONES PARA DIFERENTES USUARIOS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

quisiera que me apoyen a encontrar una idea u alternativa para el inconveniente que presento. Al iniciar la sesión con el usuario consulta debe abril el archivo consulta.php de la misma forma con el usuario soporte que al loguear me dirija al archivo soporte.php. Espero su apoyo.

-Aquí una captura de como esta formado mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Aquí una captura de los archivos .php consulta y soporte que están dentro de la carpeta vistas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Aqui el codigo en PHP de LOGIN

```
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

//recepción de datos enviados mediante POST desde ajax
$usuario = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

$pass = md5($password); //encripto la clave enviada por el usuario para compararla con la clava encriptada y almacenada en la BD

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND password='$pass' ";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();

if($resultado->rowCount() >= 1){
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["s_usuario"] = $usuario;
}else{
    $_SESSION["s_usuario"] = null;
    $data=null;
}

print json_encode($data);
$conexion=null;í
```

-Aqui una captura de mis tablas, Mi tabla usuario tiene una llave foranea id_rol
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-AQUI CODIGO JAVASCRIPT CON AJAX

```
    $('#formLogin').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var usuario = $.trim($("#usuario").val());    
   var password =$.trim($("#password").val());    

   if(usuario.length == "" || password == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:'Debe ingresar un usuario y/o password',
      });
      return false; 
    }else{
        $.ajax({
           url:"bd/login.php",
           type:"POST",
           datatype: "json",
           data: {usuario:usuario, password:password}, 
           success:function(data){               
               if(data == "null"){
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'error',
                       title:'Usuario y/o password incorrecta',
                   });
               }else{
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'success',
                       title:'¡Conexión exitosa!',
                       confirmButtonColor:'#3085d6',
                       confirmButtonText:'Ingresar'
                   }).then((result) => {
                       if(result.value){
                           window.location.href = "vistas/consulta.php";
                       }
                   })

               }
           }    
        });
    }     
});
```

Comment: En tu requerimiento de login debes hacerlo con Javascript?

Comment: Que me recomiendas ?

Comment: Primero, separaste completamente Frontend de backend? es decir, solo haces peticiones a los servicios de PHP y los consumes mediante JS ?

Comment: JS es solo para mis LOGIN - uso el PLUGIN sweetalert2, como menciono lineas arriba lo que deseo es poder loguearme con mas de un tipo de usuario y poder ser redirigido a los PHP

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar header('Location: archivo.php') ?  quizá esa función te pueda ser de utilidad, prácticamente disecciona a otra ubicación, eso por la parte de PHP. En javascript existe la función de window.location.replace('direccion') hace prácticamente lo mismo que header en PHP.

Comment: Claro pero no encuentro como aplicarlo en mi código.

Comment: Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo con mi código ?

Comment: ¿Me puedes proporcionar el JSON que genera la petición ajax ?